# What's going on with my ubuntu? How to fix it?

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I am beginning to use ubuntu. After booting up and login, it looks so different:display incomplete, malfunctional. I tried to use boot repair tool to fix it but failed. Could someone help me and tell me what's going on and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tony, you really need to provide more information so someone can assist.  What exactly is malfunctioning.  What exactly is incomplete about the display.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].